# How to read the parameters and value from the query-string using java?

Tags: java, url, servlets, character-encoding

I am using Ciui from google code and all the requests are only GET requests and not POST. The calls are made by the ajax (I am not sure). I need to know how to read the "searchstring" parameter from this URL. When I read this in my Servlet using the getQueryString() method I am not able to properly form the actual text. This unicode (when % replaced by /) like text is actually in Chinese. Please let me how to decode search string and create the string.

http://xxxx.com?searchString=%u8BF7%u5728%u6B64%u5904%u8F93%u5165%u4EA7%u54C1%u7F16%u53F7%u6216%u540D%u79F0&button=%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2

The other parameter is in proper percentage encoding an I am able to decode using the URL decode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a servlet? Why not do `request.getParameter(...)` method? (request is of type HttpServletRequest).

Comment: No. i did not get that parameter when i used request.getParameter(). So I tried using query string :(

Comment: give the javascript code that is calling the servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encoding scheme for those chinese characters actually violates web standards (namely [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)): the percent sign is a reserved character that may not be used except for the standard percent encoding.

I'd strongly advise you to use the standard encoding scheme (UTF-8 bytes and percent encoding); then you can simply use the standard `getParameter()` method. If you insist on violating the standard, it may well be impossible to solve your problem within a standards-compliant servlet container.

Answer (score 8):

Ok in my case I had the querystring from another source so you maybe need this:

```
    public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)  
{  
    String[] params = query.split("&");  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    for (String param : params)  
    {  String [] p=param.split("=");
        String name = p[0];  
      if(p.length>1)  {String value = p[1];  
        map.put(name, value);
      }  
    }  
    return map;  
}
```

So then you can use:

```
 Map params=getQueryMap(querystring);
 String id=(String)params.get("id");
 String anotherparam=(String)params.get("anotherparam");
```

Comment: This solution does not handle the case when there are multiple values associated to a single field (e.g. field1=value1&field1=value2&field1=value3).

Answer (score 2):

#### A solution with Java 8.

This piece of code transform the query string in a key/value list:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> list = 
        asList(queryString.split("&")).stream()
        .map(s -> copyOf(s.split("="), 2))
        .map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(o[0], o[1]) )
        .collect(toList());
```

the comment of @Tuno inspired me to write a new answer, this alternative (and shorter) solution use `groupingBy` method:

```
Map<String, List<String>> llist = 
       asList(queryString.split("&")).stream()
       .map(s -> copyOf(s.split("="), 2))
       .collect(groupingBy(s -> s[0], mapping(s -> s[1], toList())));
```

I suggest to decode the values with `URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)`

Both the solutions prints collection content with this line:

```
list.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getKey() + " = " + s.getValue()));
```

Comment: Nice one. I have used `.collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o[0], o -> o[1]))` to get a Map and retrieve by key.

Comment: @Tuno Your solution does not work when there are multiple values associated to a single field (e.g. `field1=value1&field1=value2&field1=value3`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String searchString = request.getParameter("searchString");
    // process searchString
}
```

Decoding the parameter is done automatically.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(Collections.list(request.getParameterNames()))` say? Is the `searchString` there? (note that it is case sensitive).