# Long lived access token by using spring social

Tags: spring, spring-social

Can any one please tell me how do i get long lived access token for the social sites with the help of `spring social`. If possible please provide the code snippet. I am using the `spring 1.1.0` `spring facebook`, `linkedIn` and `twitter` API's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. On the Facebook developer site, they have given this option for long lived access token: (Put in your values for `APP_ID`, `APP_SECRET`, and `EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`)

```
graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If we give a short lived or normal access token, we will get a long lived access token.

Answer (score 6):

For Twitter, which uses OAuth 1.0a, the tokens do not expire. So you should be getting a token that lasts virtually forever (as long as the user doesn't revoke it).

For Facebook, it's not possible (not any longer anyway) to obtain a token that lives forever. You're only option is to obtain a token and use it while you can. Once the token has expired, you must go through the authorization flow again to obtain a new token. The good news is that Spring Social provides ReconnectFilter to help you with that. See the Spring Social Showcase example (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase), specifically `SocialConfig.java` and `WebMvcConfig.java` to see how to setup `ReconnectFilter`.

My memory is a bit fuzzy on LinkedIn, but I recall that LinkedIn handles expired tokens in much the same way as Facebook (that is, you must reauthorize to get a new token). Therefore, `ReconnectFilter` should help you there, too.

Note that the behaviour described above for FB and LI is *not* in accordance with the OAuth 2 specification. Per the spec, refresh tokens are granted along with access tokens and may be used to obtain a new access token once the original has expired. FB and LI do no implement the refresh token portion of the spec. I don't know why exactly, but I suspect it's because it's more secure. If a client must redirect the user through the authorization flow to obtain a new token, then it means that the user must be actively using the application and be a participant in the renewal of the token. The per-the-spec approach doesn't require user involvement except in the initial authorization flow--the app can then renew tokens forever even if the user never uses the application again.

Comment: No in facebook developer site they have given option for long lived access token .. from this url we can get long live access token https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN   for this if we give short lived or normal access token we will get the long lived access token .. i have checked it, generated access token is working for more than 2 days..

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is not any special function prepared to exchange short-lived token to long-lived one. Here is code that works perfectly for me:

```
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "app_secret";
private static final String GRAPH_API_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String FB_EXCHANGE_TOKEN1 = "fb_exchange_token";
private static final String FB_EXCHANGE_TOKEN = "fb_exchange_token";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret";
private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "grant_type";
(...)



 public void execute(LoginFlow message) {

    URI build = UriBuilder
            .fromPath(GRAPH_API_URL)
            .queryParam(CLIENT_ID, mClientId)
            .queryParam(GRANT_TYPE, FB_EXCHANGE_TOKEN1)
            .queryParam(CLIENT_SECRET, mAppSecret)
            .queryParam(FB_EXCHANGE_TOKEN, message.getAccessToken())
            .build();

    String url = build.toString();

    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(message.getAccessToken());
    ResponseEntity<String> exchange = facebook.restOperations()
            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
    String response = exchange.getBody();
    String longTermToken = Utils.extractToken(response);
   (...)
}
```

Comment: Cool!  What is "Utils.extractToken()" ?   I found this getQueryStringParam sample code that can be usefull.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271800/how-to-read-the-parameters-and-value-from-the-querystring-using-java